# Generate 3D Surface Map from Skimage Elevation Map (2D numpy.ndarray)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-image

In [the skimage Segmentation tutorial](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/tutorial_segmentation.html#region-based-segmentation), a 3D surface plot of the elevation map generated from the `sobel` function was plotted.

```
>>> from skimage.filters import sobel
>>> elevation_map = sobel(coins)
```

[image]

**Question:** `elevation_map` appears to be a 2D `numpy.ndarray`. How do we generate the 3D map shown using this?

Comment: The height of the surface is proportional to the lightness of the pixels in the 2D array.

Comment: And I believe this was rendered using Mayavi.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely produced using Paraview/VTK;

Try to play around the following:

```
from skimage import data
from skimage.filters import sobel
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.ndimage import zoom
coins = data.coins()
coins = zoom(coins, 10)

elevation_map = sobel(coins)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

m, n=elevation_map.shape
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(n), np.arange(m))

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, elevation_map, cmap=cm.viridis, antialiased=False)
ax.axis("off")
ax.set_facecolor('black')
plt.show()
```

[image]